# Regular expression to validate input

Tags: regex, validation, numbers

I have a field that need validation.
The users shall enter exactly 18 numbers.
It can be all numbers from 0 to 9.

I tried this [0-9]{18}$
But it doesn't validate exactly 18 numbers.

Can anyone help, what I need to do?

Comment: You'll need to add an start string ancor, the caret, which matches the position before the first character of the users input > `^\d{18}$` or `^[0-9]{18}$`